# Parse ticket number from branch name and show it as default commit message in TortoiseGit on Windows

Tags: windows, tortoisegit, commit-message

My feature branches are called `feature/x_somename` where `x` is the ticket number. Everytime I start a new commit, the following shall happen:

1. Parse the ticket number from the branch name.
2. Put `refs #x:` in the commit message (where x is the ticket number).
3. Show commit dialog with the prepared commit message

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [TortoiseGit hooks](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks) (not to be confused with [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_git_hooks)):

1. Create a batch file with the following lines (just copy and paste):

   ```
   :: try to parse ticket number from branchname (expected format: "sometext/ticketnumber_sometext")
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=/_" %%i in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do set c=%%i
   :: print "refs #ticketnumber: "
   if defined c echo refs #%c%: >> %2`
   ```
2. In the TortoiseGit settings go to `Hook Scripts`.
3. Press `Add`.
4. Check `Enabled`.
5. Choose path this hook should work for (`*` for all paths)
6. Put the path to the batch script in the `Command Line To Execute` box.
7. Press `Ok` and close settings.
8. Close and reopen all other TortoiseGit windows to ensure the hook is setup.

**What does the batch file do?**
`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` returns the branchname.
The `for` command splits the result by `/` and `_`.
It will then take the second part of this split and saves it in %%i.
It then saves %%i to the variable c.
The `if` just checks if c is defined and if so prints the result.